# How to block .webp images entirely in Chrome

Tags: chromium, brave, webp

I'd like to simply block `.webp` images from my Chromium based Brave browser entirely. I don't want to see them ever again. I tried it with `AdBlock-Filtersyntax`, but to no avail: It's to complicated and poorly documented for such a simple task. I don't even get if what I want is possible with it.

How can I ban `.webp` images from my life forever?

Comment: You just don't want to see a random [yet increasing] percentage of images on the web? WebP is already up to 10% global usage & isn't going to slow down. It won't be too long before that's 50%… https://w3techs.com/technologies/details/im-webp

Comment: You can only block them after receiving the response headers (reasonably accurate) or after reading the check the first bytes of the response body. You cannot know in advance what the server will send.

Comment: "you can download a user agent spoofer extension and use *edge on windows 10* [because] edge doesn't know what webp file is," https://www.reddit.com/r/brave_browser/comments/gkwt9p/does_brave_have_a_way_to_get_around_webp_images/ . That said, **why??** .webp is just another image format. If you don't want images, just toggle Reader Mode on: https://www.theinternetpatrol.com/how-to-enable-reader-view-mode-in-the-brave-browser/

Comment: If you would like to save webp images in another format, use for example the extension [Save Image As PNG](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-image-as-png/nkokmeaibnajheohncaamjggkanfbphi) which adds an option to the browser's right-click context menu to save any image as png instead of the format it is supplied in.